# Create new columns by extracting elements in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame, I want to extract the list into another column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Q007_A00":["Y","Y","Y","Y","Y"],
               "Q007_B00": ["N","N","N","N","N"],
               "Q007_C01": [1,4,5,2,"8,3"],
               "Q007_C02": ["Text 1","Text 2","Text 3,Text 4,Text 5","Text 4","Text 5,Text 6"]})

    Q007_A00    Q007_B00    Q007_C01    Q007_C02
 0  Y           N            1          Text 1
 1  Y           N            4          Text 2
 2  Y           N            5          Text 3,Text 4,Text 5
 3  Y           N            2          Text 4
 4  Y           N            8,3        Text 5,Text 6
```

Output will be

```
Q007_A00 Q007_B00   Q007_C01 Q007_C01_1 Q007_C02 Q007_C02_1 Q007_C02_2
Y           N           1        0      Text 1    0          0
Y           N           4        0      Text 2    0          0
Y           N           5        0      Text 3    Text 4     Text 5
Y           N           2        0      Text 4    0          0
Y           N           8        3      Text 5    Text 6     0
```

The column name will add by 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `list comprehension` and [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df[x].astype(str).str.split(',', expand=True) for x in df], 
                axis=1, 
                keys=df.columns).fillna(0)
```

`MultiIndex` in columns can be removed by `list comprehension`:

```
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(col[0], col[1]) for col in df.columns]
print (df)
  Q007_A00_0 Q007_B00_0 Q007_C01_0 Q007_C01_1 Q007_C02_0 Q007_C02_1 Q007_C02_2
0          Y          N          1          0     Text 1          0          0
1          Y          N          4          0     Text 2          0          0
2          Y          N          5          0     Text 3     Text 4     Text 5
3          Y          N          2          0     Text 4          0          0
4          Y          N          8          3     Text 5     Text 6          0
```

But if need remove `_0` from column names:

```
df.columns = ['{}{}'.format(col[0], '' if col[1] == 0 else '_' + str(col[1])) 
                                                                      for col in df.columns]
print (df)
  Q007_A00 Q007_B00 Q007_C01 Q007_C01_1 Q007_C02 Q007_C02_1 Q007_C02_2
0        Y        N        1          0   Text 1          0          0
1        Y        N        4          0   Text 2          0          0
2        Y        N        5          0   Text 3     Text 4     Text 5
3        Y        N        2          0   Text 4          0          0
4        Y        N        8          3   Text 5     Text 6          0
```